# Storing and interpreting results of lm() model

Tags: r, lm

I've got data on satisfaction scores for 5 questions over a 3 year period (2016 to 2018). My objective is to determine which of the 5 questions experienced the **most statistically significant** **upward** and **downward** trend over this 3 year period.

My dummy dataframe looks like this-

```
df = data.frame(Question = c('Q1','Q1','Q1','Q2','Q2','Q2','Q3','Q3','Q3','Q4','Q4','Q4','Q5','Q5','Q5'),
                Year = c('2016','2017','2018','2016','2017','2018','2016','2017','2018','2016','2017','2018','2016','2017','2018'),
                Score = c(0.8,0.6,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.3),
                Count = c(226,117,200,323,311,380,411,408,407,222,198,201,665,668,670))
```

For this, I used the `lm` function in R to create a linear model.

```
lm(Score ~ Question * as.numeric(Year), data = df)
```

However, in order to determine the most significant upward and downward trending questions, I thought of storing the model co-efficients in a dataframe and then considering the highest and lowest co-efficients as my most significant upward and downward trending questions.

**My first question** - Am I using the right approach for what I want to achieve?

And **my second question** - If  I am using the right approach, how can I store these co-efficients in a dataframe, and filter out the top and bottom values?

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `coef(your_model)` will get a vector, or [`broom::tidy`](https://broom.tidyverse.org/) will get everything

Answer (score 0):

If you store your model, you can extract coefficients and other elements like you would from a dataframe.

An example:

```
y = as.numeric(c("1","2","3","4","5"))
x = as.numeric(c("5","6","3","10","12"))
model=lm(y~x)

model$coefficients
  (Intercept) as.numeric(x) 
    0.6350365     0.3284672
```